Ffmpeg 1080p x265 video keeps freezing when played on Raspberry Pi 4
I have some 1080p videos that I'd like to convert to x265 to reduce their size.
The problem is that when I convert them using ffmpeg, I have problems playing the resulting video on Kodi running on Raspberry Pi 4. Either video or audio freezes at certain specific times. I haven't encountered such issues with other x265 1080p videos. (And RPi4 has native HEVC hardware decoding, which allows it to play even high-res x265 video without issues.)
I use

-c:v libx265 -crf 29 -preset slow for video

and for audio

-c:a libopus -b:a 160k -af channelmap=channel_layout=5.1
-c:a libopus -b:a 112k

for different audio channels. For this reason also I need to encode such 2 audio tracks separately and then mux them together.
I tried (separately):

Reduce the maximum rate by -maxrate 3M -bufsize 6M to make sure there aren't VBR parts with too much data to process,
-tune fastdecode,
Adding -filter:a aresample=async=1000.

But neither worked. (I haven't tried combining these options together.)
What could be a cause of these issues and what else can I try?

Update: I changed my workflow to encode all channels at once using -filter:a:0 'channelmap=channel_layout=5.1'. This fixed the problem. Which means, it was apparently caused by remuxing the channels. But still I have no idea why.

Maybe it's related to mkv muxing broken.
